# Can we limit an app to not open sockets after a certain number of times?

Tags: windows, powershell, sockets, process

We have applications running on server, one of them takes all ephemeral ports and that causes port exhaustion error. We should fix this problem on server side. And we cannot kill this applications process. How can we stop application to socket opening?

Comment: Why not fix (or replace) the broken application?

Comment: Because we cant until 15 october, this season is freeze season. Actually we fix it but we cant replace it with healthy version

Comment: I would suggest that it might be worth talking to someone about if the fixes would in fact be better going into production in spite of the change freeze if it’s causing issues.

Answer (score 1):

We need more info, my first thought is to create an Outbound Rule in the firewall. But that might not be what you need if the application is to communicate freely.

A block rule for ports 0-4000 could limit the "damage". If you also need port recycle for the application I'm not sure there is a solution.